# FindFirst method of VB6 in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

Is there any possibility of using something like FindFirst, FindNext, FindLast methods, that we use in VB6?  I need to search my database before adding record, if record under current name is already there or not.
Say I have a telephone book, I donot want any name to go again without warning.
Thanks 
Furqan

Comment: It depends on what database/interface you are using with VB6 and VB.Net. If they are the same, then the FindFirst, etc., will be the same. If not, check the documentation for the database you're using in VB.net.

Comment: I am using access database but Findfirst method is not supported in vb.net

Comment: Give a code sample of your query execution stmts...

Answer (score 0):

If you allowed to use LINQ, you may use the method `Any(predicate)`.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx

Are you using ADO.NET? The Recordset Object has a `Find` method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676117.aspx